# html5 video tag autoload is not working, how to autoload in chrome or any browser

Tags: html, css

in this HTML video tag, the autoplay is not working properly, I don't know what's the problem, here is the code and link which this will show the video.

```
<video controls autoplay id="header-video">
<source src="https://winmagictoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/hairdorables.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

this is the link with the video

https://winmagictoys.com/hairdorables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Chrome don't allow autoplay media onload until user has interacted with the webpage. So you need to add an hidden autoplay iframe with silence sound.

```
<iframe src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

You can get silence sound file from here https://github.com/anars/blank-audio/blob/master/250-milliseconds-of-silence.mp3.

So your html code should be

```
<video controls autoplay id="header-video">
<source src="https://winmagictoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/hairdorables.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<iframe src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why would this work? I haven't tested it, but if anything this is a hack. Just add the `muted` attribute to a video to allow autoplay in all browsers without user interaction.

Comment: Chrome notices that a media has been played and gives the permission for autoplay in media tags.

Comment: Wow that's seriously hacky. Do not do this, tricking the browser is going to a) be broken in the future anyway once the developers catch on and b) is incredibly user unfriendly, just forcing your autoplaying video on the user. Do not recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Add `muted`. If you want to loop, you can use `loop`

```css
video {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop muted controls>
            <source src="https://winmagictoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/hairdorables.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: You really dont need those `=""` empty attributes. Just the key will do fine, and looks neater.

Comment: my bad. Edited @somethinghere

Answer (score 1):

You have to mute the video to do auto play after changing a browser policy.

Autoplay only work if your video is muted.

```html
<video controls autoplay id="header-video" muted>
<source src="https://winmagictoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/hairdorables.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<video onloadeddata="this.play();" poster="poster.png" playsinline loop muted controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.mp4.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video.mp4.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
</video>
```

Comment: You should detail _what_ you have changed and _why_. Also, the `autoplay` attribute does the same thing as `onloadeddata="this.play();"` without being inline JS and confusing. Also, if you are going to this you should consider `oncanplay` as an event instead of data. Also, you might want set the `preload` attribute in this case.

Answer (score 0):

seems like u wanna run it when the page is loaded and that is easily done with js
1st set a function in ur body tag:

```
<body onload="pageloaded()">



in js: var video = document.getElementById(header-video);   



   function pageloaded() {
video.play();
}
```

Comment: This wont wotk because video without user interaction and without muted can be blocked from playing.